# How to highlight C# Calender Control with div color

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Can any on please tell me how to highlight c# calender date with two colors green and pink 
Can i appy div colors on calender cell
if yes then how?
currently my code is

```
                    if(dt.Rows.Count>1)  
                {
                    cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    //cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                    //cell.Style.Add("color", "pink");
                    //cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
                 //foreach (var item in collection)
                    //{

                    //}
                  //  cell.Controls.Add("divColor");

                   // cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
                }

                if (dCalendarDate == tempDate)
                {

                    ViewState["ManagerID"] = iManagerID;
                    //Session["tempid"] = iManagerID;
                  //  int tempdate1 = iManagerID;
                   // if (tempid != iManagerID)
                    //{
                       // tblColorCodes clr = new tblColorCodes();
                        //clr.GetColor(tempid);



                      //}
                     DateTime tempdate2 = tempDate;


                    tblColorCodes objColorCode = new tblColorCodes();
                    objColorCode.GetColor(iManagerID);
                    string colorCode = objColorCode.ColorCode;
                    cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colorCode);
                    strJavascript = "javascript:datePic('" + day.Date + "','" + iManagerID + "');";
                    if (day.Date >= DateTime.Today)
                    {
                        cell.Attributes.Add("onclick", strJavascript);
                    }
                }

            }
            cell.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
            if (day.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(150, 150, 150);
                cell.ToolTip = "You can’t select a date in the past!";
            }
            //cell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "datePic('" + day.Date + "')");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using jQuery:

```
$('#calendarID a').each(function() {
   if (this.innerText == "14") 
   {
     this.style.color = 'red';
   }
});
```

(Or achieve the same with little more effort using JavaScript.)

This will set color of 14th day to red. If you want to combine it with your ASP.NET markup you should change calendarID to ClientID. And you can change color and the day in the similar way. You should also use css class instead of setting style properties directly.